# Regaining Lost Spell Levels from Multiclassing

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, feats, multi-classing, magic-items

So, I'm creating an optimized Rogue-Druid combination for an extremely in-depth homebrew campaign. Normally I wouldn't use this kind of build, but there are flavor reasons for doing so. This is the lay-out I have currently (+2 Racial LA from Fey'ri fully bought off):

> Druid 2 (Dragon Compendium Urban Druid variant -- 1st level only) / Rogue 1 (Wilderness Variant) / Planar Shepherd 10 / Face in the Dark 2 [Campaign homebrewed PrC -- 9/10 divine progression, 1st level no casting progression]

I'm using these items to help with the prereqs for classes:

> Wild Shape Amulet [40,000 GP, Throat] (Faerun, 167): You can wild shape as if you were a druid of four levels greater, to a maximum of 20.
>
> A pair of +2 Deadly Precision Daggers (Complete Adventurer, 127)

As it stands I've traded away 2 levels of my druid progression. With the Natural Bond feat and Wild Shape Amulet I can handle the animal companion/wild shape progression, since those compensate for it. Please also note: The feat from Complete Scoundrel that combines Rogue/Druid levels is not allowed by the DM.

My problem, however, lies in that I'm not fond of losing 2 levels of spell-caster classes.

---

**So, to the root of my question:**

Is there any way (Items, Feats, etc) I can regain these two levels? This really applies to all multiclassing losses of caster levels. In all my research and reading I do not recall coming across anything that boosts actual Spell Casting, not just CL.

*Note: It must come from one of these sources:*

> Core: DMG I-II, PHb I-II, MM I-IV and the EPH
>
> Deities & Demigods
>
> Races of: The Wild, Stone, Destiny, Ebberon, Faerun & Dragon
>
> Complete: Adventurer, Arcana, Scoundrel, Mage, Divine, Champion,
> Warrior & Psionic
>
> Tome of: Battles & Magic
>
> Stormwrack
>
> Sandstorm
>
> Dragon Magic
>
> Magic Items Compendium
>
> Spell Compendium
>
> Draconomicon
>
> Drow of the Underdark
>
> Campaign Setting: Ebberon and the Forgotten Realms
>
> Fiend Folio
>
> Unearthed Arcana
>
> Libris Mortis
>
> Heroes of: Horror & Battle
>
> Fiendish Codex I & II
>
> Lords of Madness
>
> Book of: Exalted Deeds & Vile Darkness
>
> Dragon Compendium
>
> Miniatures Handbook

Comment: Ultimately, the two questions are *slightly* different, but the answer is the same: no, there is no way to regain lost spellcasting levels.